# Cookie value is not changing. Each time getting the previous value

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I am using cookies. When you first time open the page i set the cookie like this

```
public class SessionTimeoutFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        Object isRegistered = session.getAttribute("logedin");
         if (isRegistered != null) {
             String isRegisteredUser = isRegistered.toString();
             if (isRegisteredUser.equalsIgnoreCase(("1"))) {
                 sessionID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();               
                 session.setMaxInactiveInterval(240);   //4min
                 Cookie userCookie = getCookie(httpServletRequest, "userCookie");
                 if (userCookie != null) {

                      //Value not setting here
                      Cookie loginUserCookie = new Cookie("userCookie", "loginUser");
                      httpServletResponse.addCookie(loginUserCookie);
                 }
                 filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
             }
         } else {
             sessionID = httpServletRequest.getRequestedSessionId();
             sessionValid = httpServletRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid();

            //User open his browser
            if (sessionID == null && !sessionValid) {
                sessionID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                Cookie browserCookie = new Cookie("browserCookie", sessionID);
                httpServletResponse.addCookie(browserCookie); 
                Cookie userCookie = new Cookie("userCookie", "normal");
                httpServletResponse.addCookie(userCookie);

                session.setAttribute("logedin", "0");
                filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);

            //Session expires. Each time user close the tab and session expires automatically
            } else if(sessionID != null && !sessionValid) { 
                if (httpServletRequest.isRequestedSessionIdFromCookie()) {
                    Cookie userCookie = getCookie(httpServletRequest, "userCookie");
                    String value = userCookie.getValue();

                    //Each time getting normal
                    if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("normal")) {
                        session.setAttribute("logedin", "0");
                        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
                    } else if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("loginUser")) {

                    }
                } //end of if (httpServletRequest.isRequestedSessionIdFromCookie())
            }
         }
   } //end of dofilter()
} //end of class SessionTimeoutFilter
```

When first time you open the page then the condition `if (sessionID == null && !sessionValid)` becomes true and the userCookie set to value normal.Now if you close the browser tab, then open the page again. The cookie value is normal. OK.

But now when you log in then it comes to condition `if (isRegisteredUser.equalsIgnoreCase(("1")))`. Here i am trying to replace the userCookie value , like

```
Cookie userCookie = getCookie(httpServletRequest, "userCookie");

            if (userCookie != null) {

                String value = userCookie.getValue();

                //delete the cokie
                //userCookie.setValue("loginUser");
                //userCookie.setMaxAge(0);

                Cookie loginUserCookie = new Cookie("userCookie", "loginUser");
                httpServletResponse.addCookie(loginUserCookie);

            }
```

But both the approaches are not working. Now after doing that if i close the browser, and open the page again, then in the condition

```
if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("normal")) {

    session.setAttribute("logedin", "0");
    filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);

} else if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("loginUser")) {

}
```

I am getting normal again as userCookie value..This time it should get me value "loginUser", because i have changed the value of userCookie to loginUser.  BUt i am getting normal here.  Why i am getting the previous value. what i am doing wrong? Please tell me.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set the cookie path, solve the problem like

```
Cookie userCookie = new Cookie("userCookie", "loginUser");
userCookie.setPath("/");
httpServletResponse.addCookie(userCookie);
```

After setting cookie path, value is replaced.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you a cookie do not have an expiry or max age defined - it is considered a session cookie, which will be removed automatically when user closes his browser. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age

You have to set an expiry date for your cookie. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setMaxAge(int)

```
            Cookie loginUserCookie = new Cookie("userCookie", "loginUser");
            loginUserCookie.setMaxAge(3600); // cookie expires in an hour 
            httpServletResponse.addCookie(loginUserCookie);
```

Comment: ok, it's a session level cookie, agreed. But what if i want to change the value of session level cookie. On page open, my session level cookie has value normal, when user log in, then i want to change the value of session level cookie. Is there any need to set the expiry of cookie , when you just want to change the value of your cookie? Thanks

Comment: By the way, you can use any HTTP Traffic monitor (for example FireBug plugin for Firefox) to check which (and how exactly) cookies are set/transferred  in your application.